# Get most recent MySQL transaction only

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to export a set of user information from one WordPress database to import into another database.  However I'm having trouble figuring out how to only export the most recent membership transaction for a user.  The following query exports all transactions for each user, but I only want the transaction with the most recent "t.expires_at" value.  I've tried various sub-queries etc based on other StackOverflow threads but can't quite figure it out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.user_login AS user_login, 
    u.user_email AS user_email, 
    u.user_registered AS user_registered, 
    f.meta_value AS first_name, 
    l.meta_value AS last_name,
    t.expires_at AS membership_enddate
FROM 
    wp_acfzia_users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_acfzia_usermeta AS f
    ON u.ID = f.user_id AND f.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_acfzia_usermeta AS l
    ON u.ID = l.user_id AND l.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN
    wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions AS t
    ON u.ID = t.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.user_login AS user_login, 
    u.user_email AS user_email, 
    u.user_registered AS user_registered, 
    f.meta_value AS first_name, 
    l.meta_value AS last_name,
    t.expires_at AS membership_enddate
FROM 
    wp_acfzia_users AS u
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_acfzia_usermeta AS f
    ON u.ID = f.user_id AND f.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN 
    wp_acfzia_usermeta AS l
    ON u.ID = l.user_id AND l.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN
    wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions AS t
    ON u.ID = t.user_id
WHERE exists (
   select 1 from tbl where tbl.user_id = t.user_id 
   having max(tbl.expires_at) = t.expires_at
)
```

---

or MySQL 8+

```
select * from (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        u.user_login AS user_login, 
        u.user_email AS user_email, 
        u.user_registered AS user_registered, 
        f.meta_value AS first_name, 
        l.meta_value AS last_name,
        t.expires_at AS membership_enddate,
        row_number() over (order by t.expires_at partition by user_id) rn
    FROM 
        wp_acfzia_users AS u
    LEFT JOIN 
        wp_acfzia_usermeta AS f
        ON u.ID = f.user_id AND f.meta_key = 'first_name'
    LEFT JOIN 
        wp_acfzia_usermeta AS l
        ON u.ID = l.user_id AND l.meta_key = 'last_name'
    LEFT JOIN
        wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions AS t
        ON u.ID = t.user_id
)
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: The first version worked, although I had to change tbl in the where clause to wp_acfzia_mepr_transactions.  I couldn't test the second version since the server is running v5.7 of MySQL.  Thanks for the help.